# Border that bulges near mouse pointer

Tags: wpf, styles

I have a `ListView` populated with `ListViewItems`, like navigation bar style menu options.

I would like to create the effect of the `ListViewItem` border "bulging" like in the Mail application on Win10 as shown in this picture

[image]

The border "bulges" (fisheye?) as the mouse moves left and right along the `ListViewItem`.  It's a nice effect that I'd like to replicate but am struggling to even get started on how to tackle this.

My list items are bound to a content control which is templated with a `ControlTemplate`.  The `ItemsControl` `ItemTemplate` is a `DataTemplate` containing an image and a Textbox wrapped inside a button control, like this .... (although I suspect how it's created is probably not relevant to my question)

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=MenuModel.AllMenuItems}" 
                x:Name="menuCtrl1" 
                Template="{StaticResource MenuListItemControlTemplate}"  
                VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

...

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuListItemControlTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Border Background="Transparent" >
        <ScrollViewer Margin="{StaticResource DefaultNoMargin}"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuListItemDataTemplate}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

...

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MenuListItemDataTemplate" DataType="local:SingleMenuItem">
    <Button Command="{Binding MenuCommand}" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Image Source="{Binding MenuIconSource}" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemImage}" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding DisplayText}" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

Any tips on how to achieve it or even where to start would be gratefully received.

Comment: This seems like this might be a bit complex, just to give you a heads up. It might be more helpful to think to the effect not as actually changing the shape of the item, but just adding an aditional element that decorates the top and bottom. Looks like some element with a [`RadialGradientBrush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.radialgradientbrush), which follows the mouse's X coordinate when while it's over the item.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Keith ... that's kinda the direction I'm heading in ... I can capture the mouse position but was struggling to work out how to apply a GradientBrush to a border item ... perhaps using the mouse position as an offset for the GradientBrush ... it just seemed massively complex for what should be a "relatively" simple task.  I'll keep at it because nothing I've tried so far is even getting close to a solution.  Thanks, Tim.

Comment: Try making the top and bottom as seperate elements, and make them the width of the intended "bulge". Then the `Brush` can stay constant and you only have to move the borders around with the mouse.

Comment: Thanks again Keith.  I'll give this a try and report back on my success or failure :-)

Comment: Ever make any progress with this?

Comment: Not yet Keith - I had to park the project for a short while but will be getting back to it soon ... I'll comment here if and when I have any progress.  Thanks for your interest though.